# ObjC: Statics are not consistent across multiple frameworks when contained in cocoapod

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

So my situation specifically uses the Objection dependency injection library. However, I believe this could be an issue for other libraries as well.

**Platform**

iOS 8.0 Xcode 6.1.1. Cocoapods 0.35. Objective-C.

**Set up:**

I have 4 projects. 3 universal frameworks and a test app (I'm creating an api). The test app does not utilize cocoapods (though some other app might).

All three of my frameworks need to use injection. I created a pod file that looks like

```
workspace 'workspace.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '8.0'

xcodeproj 'path/to/proj/one'
xcodeproj 'path/to/proj/two'
xcodeproj 'path/to/proj/three'

target :Project1 do
  pod 'Objection', '1.4'
end

target :Project2 do
  pod 'Objection', '1.4'
end

target :Project3 do
  pod 'Objection', '1.4'
  pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7.1'
end
```

**Problem**

When I use this set up singletons don't work in Objection. However, they only don't work if they (the singleton class) is defined in project 1 and then I call `[JSObjection createInjector];` in project 2 (the projects don't make a difference, it is that create is called in a different project to the definition).

**Current theory**

After battling with this for a while I believe it is due to the warning along the lines of:

```
Objection is defined in Project 1, Project 2 and Project 3.
Which one will be used undefined.
```

So when the class registers itself with the injection system (e.g through `objection_register_singleton(ClassX)`). It is using the JSObjection definition from its project, which might not be the one being used for a class that injects it (e.g. `objection_requires_sel(@selector(myClassXObject))`).

**Question**

I want to be able to use the iOS frameworks setup as, from what I understand, it is better overall than static libs. However, I also want to be able to use Cocoapods (and have any app, that uses my api, use Cocoapods).

How do I either a) share one definition across multiple frameworks or b) setup a framework as a Cocoapod (I've seen that this is being developed).

I would love to be able to keep the frameworks linked through the xcode workspace so when one is built the frameworks it depends on are also built. Though having said that, my api will probably become a Cocoapod at some point anyway.

Thanks in advance (and for reading to here)

Indigo

Comment: Because you use the same target three times? Don't you see that?

Comment: Sorry that was an input mistake. Edited it. In the actual code I do use different targets.

Comment: It looks like Objection is the problem. You should edit your question title and tags to make that clearer, so somebody who knows  how Objection works can help answer your question.

Comment: Hi Abhi, as I say in my question my case is specifically Objection, however, if I am correct about the cause it is a wider problem (or just different semantics) in Cocoapods.
As the problem (I think) is due to the multiple implementations (or imports really) of the pod.

Comment: CocoaPods had issues with multiple targets when I checked last time on 0.33